# Password at fixed date excel file

Tags: excel

Is it possible to make an excel file ask for a password at specific date to continue using this file.So how can I do it using excel?

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of normally but you could use some code to do it. Put this in the code for the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
owb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
If Date > "13/07/2015" Then
    Pass = InputBox("Enter Password")
    If Pass <> "test" Then
    Workbooks(owb).Close
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Just change the date to the date you want it to start asking for a password and change test to the password you want. this is not very secure but would stop most also it does not hide the password as your typing it.

Don't know if this helps or not.